# Why is specialized hardware required for virtual-to-physical memory address translation but not e.g. file path decoding?

Tags: operating-system, hardware, virtual-memory

I'm currently solving a practice exam for my Operative Systems class and stumbled upon a question I can't find the answer to (we are not provided with the answers).

The question is: "Why is it important to use hardware to translate between virtual and physical addresses, but hardware is not necessary to translate for example the name of a file and it's location on disk" (sorry if anything gets lost in translation)

I'll take any help you can give!

Answer (score 1):

I'll try to answer the question as completely as possible without going into too much detail.

Specialized hardware is not necessary for file path decoding because

- files are generally opened in a rather infrequent manner
- not every process opens any files at all
- you only need to decode the file path once in order to access the file
- file access is generally very slow and is a performance bottleneck already, so the relative cost of decoding the file path in software is negligible.

Specialized hardware is necessary for memory address translation because

- a translation has to be made every single time memory is accessed
- pretty much every process in existence writes to memory, and does so frequently
- the address has to be decoded every time memory is accessed
- memory access is relatively fast and the relative cost of performing the address translation in software would be enormous
- such hardware makes [multi-level page tables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Page_table#Multilevel_page_table) used in modern systems feasible.

So, it is essentially about *making the common case fast* - a widely applied principle in computer system design.

Finally, I'll have to stress the fact that memory protection as we know it would be basically impossible to implement in software - it really would be *that* slow.

Comment: There _are_ feasible alternatives, although they are nowhere near being equivalent: [Inferno](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inferno_%28operating_system%29) which uses a virtual machine for user space, and the [QEMU](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QEMU) JIT binary translator. The first one isn't an MMU and the second one is effectively an emulator, but the latter shows that JIT could achieve _less_ frequent address translations iirc.